# The \slice{} command from quantikz doesn't work

Tags: graphics, quantikz

I have tried writting some circuits and wanted to put slices to better explain what was going on after every gate. The problem is that when I tried to use the command the slices end up on the same spot.

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{quantikz}

\begin{document}
    

        \begin{quantikz}
            & \qw\slice{1}   & \gate{H}\slice{2} &\ctrl{1}\slice{3} & \qw \\
            & \qw & \qw      & \targ{}  & \qw \\
        \end{quantikz}

    
\end{document}
```

This is the code that I used and this is what I get as a result:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unclear from your question but I think this is what you're looking for. Note that `quantikz` was updated recently (hence the `\usetikzlibrary{quantikz2}`) and the syntax changed slightly; in particular the commands `\vcw`, `\vqw`, `\qw`, `\cw`, and `\cwbend` were deprecated.

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{quantikz2}

\begin{document}

\begin{quantikz}
\slice{1} & \gate{H} \slice{2} & \ctrl{1} \slice{3} & \\
& & \targ{} &
\end{quantikz}

\end{document}
```

[image: quant]